# Using jcarousel.js - saving the images and position exactly, after navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jcarousel

I am using `jcarousel.js` plugin to order `<ul>` list of images in my `jQuery Mobile` app with carousel affect. Each time I initialize my page the images are different (comes from WS) so after I set them into `<ul>` I call it like this:

```
 $('#imagesPageDiv').live('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
                   jQuery('#carouselDiv').jcarousel({ visible: 4, scroll: 2});
              });
```

It works fine.

Each image have `URL` to that same big image.The problem occurs when coming back to that same page.

I dont want to set the images from start, want to come back exactly to the same images and the place (image position) before I clicked on it.
I set `flag`, so basically I know when I'm coming back and when I starting it from start.
So I tried to save all the page before navigating to the next page, and after coming back append it again to the page:

```
  globalDivContent = $('#imagesPage #box');
```

After coming back to that page I appending it:

```
 $("#imagesPage").empty();
   $("#imagesPage").append(globalDivContent );
```

Realy getting the same courosel with the real images and posstion exepct one problem: it    doesnt scroll's.
   The arrows are clickable but aren't doing nothing

I compared the codes when starting the page and coming back to page and it similar. Any ideas how can i implement my idea?

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" />    
                <script src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>                    
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
                <script>
                      $('#imagesPage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
                      jQuery('#carouselDiv').jcarousel({visible:2});
       });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div data-role="page" id="imagesPage">
                    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                        <h1>Index page</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="content">
                        <ul id="carouselDiv" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                            <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="65" height="65" alt=""/></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: JavaScript variables are not persistent across page loads, so 'divContent' will not contain the previous content.

Comment: No no,its OK. I have a global var and I'm saving the content to it,I do transfer the content.

Comment: Unfortunately, window variables can only store strings, not complex structuresa (such as a jQuery Object). The only way you could persist it in this way would be to serialize it to a string first and then unserialize it when you retrieve it.

Comment: I think we need to see the script in action to be able to advise on the issue. There are so many things that could affect the navigation that it's unlikely we'll come up with an answer without it.

Comment: Added more code. I dont understand what kind of problem I have store complex structure - it's string. using :  `globalDivContent = $('#imagesPage #box');` I have all the HTML code.

Comment: Have you tried putting your jCarousel call at the bottom of the page, or wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function(){ /* ... */ })`? (pageshow isn't very widely supported)

Comment: Yes did it,but the question is how to save the state?! I dont have any problems initialization it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise saving only the information you need, rather than copying the entire div in one go. This would allow you to cherry-pick the data your really need and safely persist it across page loads.

The best solution for this would be to use local storage. This allows you to save string-to-string values persistently across a site as far back as IE8 (see more information here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage).

For example, you could save your data like this:

```
localStorage["carouselSource"] = JSON.stringify(
    $('#carouselDiv li img').map(function(i,e){
        return $(this).attr('src');
    }).get();
);
```

and retrieve it like this (before the jCarousel call):

```
var items = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage["carouselSource"]);

jQuery.each(items, function(i,e){
    $('#carouselDiv').append('<li><img src="' + e + '" width="65" height="65" alt="" /></li>');
});
```

This would ensure that the same set of images are displayed when the user returns to the page. You could use a similar technique to save things like the position of the slider and any other variable data you want to save.

Comment: Sounds nice...so basically I can use a global parameter(or storage) for saving the syntax, and then simply append it.

Comment: I would recommend against saving the entire syntax, and instead saving just the contents of the src attributes of the images and any other relevant meta data (such as slide position). That way you can populate and initialize the slider cleanly from localStorage if any data is present or, if not, draw the images from Flickr. Saving the entire syntax might work, but it would be more of a hack than a solution.